# Function dropped when transpiling from TypeScript to JavaScript

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript file with 12 functions. When this file is transpiled into a JavaScript file only 11 functions are copied over. One function (that I am actually using in my source) is dropped:

```
function getControlSize(id: string) {
    const control = document.getElementById(id);

    if ((control == null) || (control.clientWidth < 1) || (control.clientHeight < 1)) return "800 600";

    return control.clientWidth + " " + control.clientHeight;
}
```

Anyone has a clue why this is happening? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
function showAlert(message: string): string { 
    alert(message); 
    return message; 
} 

function getControlSize(id: string) { 
    const control = document.getElementById(id); 
    if ((control == null) || (control.clientWidth < 1) || 
    (control.clientHeight < 1)) 
    return "800 600"; 

    return control.clientWidth + " " + control.clientHeight; 
} 

function getWindowWidth(): number { 
    if (window == null) 
    return -1; 

    return window.innerWidth; 
}
```

Comment: But all the other functions also start with 'func', so why is this function different?

Comment: Please show the content of the entire file. Otherwise it would only be hip shooting to name the error.

Comment: Showing the entire file would take too much space, let me show you the preceding and following function as well:

Comment: The only difference I can see is, that your omitted function carries no return type although you actually do return a value. Maybe your compiler options are so restrictive, that this method is left out just because of the missing return type.

Comment: You are correct: I missed out the return type of the function. Thanks. Unfortunately setiing the return type to `string` did not solve the issue.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't imagine any other reason without seeing the entire file. Maybe you can put it on stackblitz or any other page of the same type?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll wait and see if someone else on StackOverflow has an idea.

Comment: @PaultenBrink how did you call the function? or how did you know that it is dropped, there's nothing wrong in your code

Comment: Also, how are you compiling your code? Do you get any meaningful error or warning from TSC?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2017, there is no error when building the project. I know the function is missing because it is not present in the generated JavaScript file.